# Как на Swing реализовать панель с вкладками слева

Tags: java, swing, form

[image: example - пример]

никак не могу найти этот вариант, помогите пожалуйста))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это делается с помощью компонента `JTabbedPane`. Для того, чтобы закладки были слева, нужно создавать его конструктором с параметром, например, так:

```
     JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
```

Cм. подробнее:
документация по JTabbedPane: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html

Самоучитель: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Статья на русском: https://javaswing.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/jtabbedpane/

Comment: спасибо большое, ты мой герой красавчик ;-)

Comment: @OldBlood Комплименты мне делать не надо, а ответ отметить как решение можно :) Можно даже плюсануть, если понравилось :)

Comment: пока не могу плюсануть :) и еще раз спасибо